# Reference a Cell in '=IMPORTXML'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been writing a formula to import tiktok views into a google sheets document this is what I have so far:

=importXML( {TIKTOK WEBPAGE LINK} ,"//a[contains(@href, '{SPECIFIC LINK TV}')]//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']")

TV = TikTok

The place holders {TIKTOK WEBPAGE LINK} & {SPECIFIC LINK TO TIKTOK VIDEO FROM WEBPAGE} work when I input the links manually. Is there a way to reference a cell value, for example G2, for {SPECIFIC LINK TV}?

I tried simply adding G2 in the place of {SPECIFIC LINK TV}.I removed some " " to remove the string aspect of it and that didn't work. I also tried a method from StackOverflow titled "Trying to reference a cell in importxml". The formula is a slightly different from mine but I am not used to these excel functions and would like some help.The results were all the video views (down the column). I simply just want one value for the specific TikTok link.

P.S This would be fine if I only had 1 vid to look at but I have hundreds of videos and want to be able to reference select vids without having to manually change the URLs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=importXML(A2,"//a[contains(@href,'"&B2&"')]//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']")
```

[image]